# How to check CPU temperature on a HP P2000?

Tags: storage, hp, physical-environment

I have an [HP StorageWorks MSA Storage P2000 G3 SAS](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF05a/12169-304616-241493-241493-241493-4118559.html?dnr=1) array.

`show sensor-status` gives something like

```
# show sensor-status
Sensor Name                       Value    Status   
----------------------------------------------------
On-Board Temperature 1-Ctlr A     53 C     OK       
On-Board Temperature 1-Ctlr B     52 C     OK       
On-Board Temperature 2-Ctlr A     61 C     OK       
On-Board Temperature 2-Ctlr B     63 C     OK       
On-Board Temperature 3-Ctlr A     53 C     OK       
On-Board Temperature 3-Ctlr B     53 C     OK       
Disk Controller Temp-Ctlr A       34 C     OK       
Disk Controller Temp-Ctlr B       32 C     OK       
Memory Controller Temp-Ctlr A     66 C     OK       
Memory Controller Temp-Ctlr B     67 C     OK       
[...]
Overall Unit Status               OK       OK       
Temperature Loc: upper-IOM A      40 C     OK       
Temperature Loc: lower-IOM B      38 C     OK       
Temperature Loc: left-PSU         36 C     OK       
Temperature Loc: right-PSU        40 C     OK       
[...]
```

is one of the values the CPU/FPGA temperature? Or, if not, how do I get it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a strange request. Why are you concerned about the temperature of the CPU of one component of this SAN, versus overall system and ambient temperature?

(edit) It looks like you have a cooling problem. Those are slightly high temperatures!

Either way, here's the output from my HP P2000 G3 SAS storage unit... The first four values are for the CPU's and [FPGA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array) units for each of the two controllers in the system. You can also pull this information via SNMP against the controller IP address(es):

```
# show sensor-status
Sensor Name                       Value    Status   
----------------------------------------------------
CPU Temperature-Ctlr A            41       OK       
CPU Temperature-Ctlr B            41       OK       
FPGA Temperature-Ctlr A           42       OK       
FPGA Temperature-Ctlr B           44       OK       
Onboard Temperature 1-Ctlr A      27       OK       
Onboard Temperature 1-Ctlr B      27       OK       
Onboard Temperature 2-Ctlr A      35       OK       
Onboard Temperature 2-Ctlr B      36       OK       
Capacitor Temperature-Ctlr A      23       OK       
Capacitor Temperature-Ctlr B      23       OK       
Capacitor Pack Voltage-Ctlr A     8.22     OK       
Capacitor Pack Voltage-Ctlr B     8.12     OK       
Capacitor Cell 1 Voltage-Ctlr A   2.06     OK       
Capacitor Cell 1 Voltage-Ctlr B   2.02     OK       
Capacitor Cell 2 Voltage-Ctlr A   2.04     OK       
Capacitor Cell 2 Voltage-Ctlr B   2.02     OK       
Capacitor Cell 3 Voltage-Ctlr A   2.05     OK       
Capacitor Cell 3 Voltage-Ctlr B   2.03     OK       
Capacitor Cell 4 Voltage-Ctlr A   2.08     OK       
Capacitor Cell 4 Voltage-Ctlr B   2.05     OK       
Capacitor Charge-Ctlr A           99%      OK       
Capacitor Charge-Ctlr B           99%      OK       
Overall Unit Status               OK       OK       
Temperature Loc:upper-IOM A       34       OK       
Temperature Loc:lower-IOM B       33       OK       
Temperature Loc:left-PSU 1        29       OK       
Temperature Loc:right-PSU 2       26       OK       
Voltage 12V Loc:upper-IOM         11.86    OK       
Voltage 5V Loc:upper-IOM          5.05     OK       
Voltage 12V Loc:lower-IOM         11.86    OK       
Voltage 5V Loc:lower-IOM          5.05     OK       
Voltage 12V Loc:left-PSU 1        12.04    OK       
Voltage 5V Loc:left-PSU 1         5.12     OK       
Voltage 3.3V Loc:left-PSU 1       3.67     OK       
Voltage 12V Loc:right-PSU 2       12.04    OK       
Voltage 5V Loc:right-PSU 2        5.11     OK       
Voltage 3.3V Loc:right-PSU 2      3.68     OK       
Current 12V Loc:upper-IOM         4.20     OK       
Current 12V Loc:lower-IOM         4.24     OK       
Current 12V Loc:left-PSU 1        7.42     OK       
Current 5V Loc:left-PSU 1         5.57     OK       
Current 12V Loc:right-PSU 2       5.76     OK       
Current 5V Loc:right-PSU 2        4.78     OK       
----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm wondering why I don't have those CPU/FPGA lines in the beginning. Is it perhaps due to a different controller version? Mine is `TS230P007`. Or do I really lack those sensors in my system? You're right, I have a cooling problem, that's why I'm concerned about the particular sensor values. The "Onboard" danger threshold is at 70 C, which is OK, but I can't figure out the temperature of the CPU.

Comment: Yeah, you *should* have those sensors. Try to reset each controller, one at a time, and see if that brings the sensors online.

Answer (score 1):

A P2000 doesn't just have one big CPU that does everything, it has a number of parts to increase the units reliability and you're seeing those parts listed there. There are two controllers in your box (some have only one) and each has a number of sensors for the controllers and one more for both the port (disk) controller and the cache (memory) controllers - so you have the lot already.

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of the complexity of the overall storage system, I just need to check how close the sensor values are to the danger thresholds. [Here](http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02006876/c02006876.pdf) I found the thresholds (Table 10 on page 63), now I need to know the real temperature.